# android native or HTML5 to use in a transactional offline/online mobile app

Tags: android, html, mobile

I am going to develop a mobile application used by our company salesmen to make orders and DB transactions.
initially we target mobile with android OS.
I have 2 option for the technology will be used.

1. using HTML5
2. using android native API.

**My question is:**
depending on the following set of features, what is the best technology choice to achieve this job ??

**Note:** we prefer to use HTML5 to be platform independent but we are not sure if HTML5 will give us all needed app features.

***Its preferred that the app contains these features :***

1. the salesmen will use this app to record invoices, make orders,
   view some reports , and  making customer survey.
2. the app should
   be able to work online and offline as well.
3. the app should has
   its own offline DB. (to store offline transactions)
4. the app
   contain option for sync with the main DB server to post the offline
   created transactions to the live server. (when salesman back to home
   Or when internet connection is available.)
5. the app has some
   special user interface requirements, so flexible user interface
   design is highly needed.
6. ability to lock all phone features
   (other app, camera, sim card and so on) and allowing salesman to
   open and access only our developed application.
7. ability to access GPS native API in the mobile to allocate the salesman position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ability to lock all phone features (other app, camera, sim card and so on) and allowing salesman to open and access only our developed application.

You wont get anywhere close to this behavior from an html 5 app. And even if you go with native (unless you're willing to modify the OS) you aren't going to be able to completely lock it down like you are wanting.

Either way my vote is for a native app. At this point native is ( in my opinion ) always going to provide you with a finished product that is nicer to use.

Comment: The OP should look at developing this app for a dedicated mobile computer platform instead of a phone. http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers for example

Comment: I agree. Although the fact that it is even possible to do this with the computers that we call "phones" is the one of the most exciting things about the current state of mobile.

Comment: Thanks Tim,we could able to lock the OS features in our old .net app which worked on windows mobile OS by playing with registry, So I think this option is found in android, Also regardless of locking all phone features, is ur vote still for Native ?? and why please.

Comment: It is certainly possible to do with the android platform. But you'll have to create your own version of the platform to enable it. It won't(hopefully) work on a device that is running a stock OS build. And yes, my vote is still for a Native application. In my opinion it simply provides a better and more responsive user experience.