# Should I create a feed inside app using HTML5 or Native Code?

Tags: android, html, memory, native

We're building a new Android application and we have some Facebook/Instagram like feeds in it.
I would like to hear your opinion for how to implement the feeds - HTML5 or Native.

If I use Native code in Android I will have to manage the memory of the pictures in the feed, but the memory still limited and not enough for about 15-20 pictures (we can easily need more) than you get OutOfMemoryException.

If I use HTML5 is the memory issue not a problem? I know will have an adventage of cross platform ready feeds.

Please, feel free to post your insights on this situation.

As I heard, Facebook and Instagram using HTML5 feeds inside native app.

Thank you all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android native or HTML5 to use in a transactional offline/online mobile app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574605/android-native-or-html5-to-use-in-a-transactional-offline-online-mobile-app)